# Write file on read request - Linux

Tags: linux, io, system-calls

I want a specific file to be written whenever any program is attempting to read it. For example, I create an empty file, or filled with zeros,  a program tries to read N bytes starting from the M-th byte of the file (using read/seek syscalls), and I need to make the read call wait until I write the requested bytes to the file to make the syscall successfully read written bytes without errors. The file should look as the one a program is expecting to read. Or is there a way to "send" needed bytes to the read() call without writing them directly to the file before that? I need to make it work with any program without editing its code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This must be done by intercepting the filesystem read requests at the kernel level. The simplest approach would be to leverage [FuseFS](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) to implement a filesystem filter in userspace. The other programs would be reading from your fileyststem, giving you full control over what they read.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to create your own synchronization protocol between the read and writer using some IPC mechanism.

Alternatively, you could do this in a database using stored procedures.